# Adding drag drop functionality in Vue Splitpanes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable, splitpane, html5-draggable

I am trying to add Drag-drop functionality in [Vue Splitpane](https://antoniandre.github.io/splitpanes/). I was trying several drag-drop packages i.e. [vue-smooth-dnd](https://kutlugsahin.github.io/vue-smooth-dnd/#/cards), [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable), etc. But, those dnd packages were conflicting with the splitpane package as it strictly maintains the structure such as:

```
<splitpanes>
    <pane> 
    </pane>
</splitpanes>
```

So, I was looking for options of adding drag-drop as directive to the element. I have found this, [vue-draggable](https://vivify-ideas.github.io/vue-draggable/) package and implemented it. Drag-drop is working now but it can't drag the `splitpanes__splitter` div after the `<pane>` element (`div.splitpanes__pane`). So, resizing option of the pane is not moving along the pane and that's why resizing option is not visible after every pane. How can make it work properly?

**[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/oNqEZNz)**

Answer (score 0):

Due to how Vue works, I think you're going to really struggle getting those two components to place nice with one another.

You'll be much better off implementing your own drag+drop using the [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API), as in the long run, it'll be much quicker than trying, and inevitably failing, to mesh those two components together.